# Uso de JOINS en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

para hoy tengo un reto   se trata de hacer consultas en SQL Server con el uso de JOINS, si alguien me puede ayudar seria genial  la verdad no conozco del tema y apenas estoy apendiendo a crear una base de datos  con algunas tablas ..

Comment: ¿Investigaste algo previamente?
Anexo un enlace que podría ayudarte. https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/Fundamentos-de-SQL-Consultas-SELECT-multi-tabla-Tipos-de-JOIN.aspx

Comment: Recomiendo que investigues un poco mñas en internet antes de hacer una pregunta, es un tema que es facil de encontrar en internet. Te dejo un link que en mi opinion lo tiene muy bien explicado https://diego.com.es/principales-tipos-de-joins-en-sql

Answer (score 4):

En SQL Server se pueden hacer consultas con JOIN de la siguiente forma:

```
INNER JOIN -- Que retorna data que tiene similitud entre ambas tablas

LEFT JOIN -- Que retorna data de la tabla de la izquierda y los datos que 
-- tengan similitud de la tabla derecha

RIGHT JOIN -- Que retorna data de la tabla derecha y los datos que tengan 
-- similitud de la tabla izquierda

FULL JOIN -- Retorna data de ambas tablas ya sea que haya similitud en la 
-- izquierda o en la derecha
```

Answer (score 1):

amigo también soy nuevo en sql pero gracias a esta página me pude fundamentar un poco mas 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

por ejemplo en el link que adjunté se pueden ver sintaxis sobre los joins como esta:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

tiene ejemplos y unos "do it yourself" lo cual te permite aprender un poco más con algunos ejercicios prácticos y si manejas mssql busca la documentación de microsoft que es muy util

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], hacer aportes con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad

Comment: me disculpo por haber hecho mi respuesta de tal manera, con gusto voy  a leer lo que recomendaste